# How can i get the Id of the Todo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to delete am item by id but i keep get error, that each child should have a unique key after giving a it an id, what am i doing wrongly, why am i not getting the id

```
const TodoList = () => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

    const handleSubmit = e => {

        e.preventDefault()

        setTodos([...todos, input])
        setInput("")
    }

    const handleDelete = id => {

       let item =  todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id)

       console.log(item)
    //    setTodos(item)
    }




  return (
  <div className='todolist'>
      <h2>Todo List</h2>
      <form>
          <input value={input} onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)} placeholder='write something' />
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add todo</button>
      </form>
      {todos.map(todo => (

          <div key={todo.id}  className='todolist__details'>
              <h2>{todo}</h2>
              <DeleteIcon onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)} />
          </div>
      ))}
  </div>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: you can't set unique id in `todos` array !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {todos.map((todo, i) => {
        <div key={i}  className='todolist__details'>
              <h2>{todo}</h2>
              <DeleteIcon onClick={() => handleDelete(i)} />
          </div>
    })}
```

You can check how list and keys work in react in here

> https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 2):

From the above code, it looks like todos is an array of strings. So when you are assigning `key` by doing `todo.id`, you are assigning the `key` to be `undefined` since the `id` property does not exist in the `string` type. Change you map method like this

```
{todos.map((todo, i) => (
    <div key={i}  className='todolist__details'>
        <h2>{todo}</h2>
        <DeleteIcon onClick={() => handleDelete(i)} />
    </div>
))}
```

and then change on your `handleDelete` like

```
const handleDelete = id => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(id, 1);
    console.log(newTodos)
    setTodos(newTodos)
}
```

Comment: You have to specify key if using array.map function it is to help React differentiate and distinguish elements from each other, increasing its performance when diffing between the virtual and real DOM

Comment: please can i update a particuar todo item

Comment: how do you want to do it? Can you update your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given id to any of your todo , Pass the index of that todo instead of id , it will solve your problem
Try this sandbox code [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-buck-dydwc?file=/src/App.js)

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As other users (especially TheWhiteFang) pointed out above, your todos list is an array, and your single todo item inside this array is string which you get from your input.

Alternatively, you could set your single todo item as an object instead of plain string, such as `{id: 1, content: input}`, for example, change the line of setTodos to:

```
setTodos([...todos, { id: count, content: input }]);
```

In this way, you could then access the id of every single todo item and access the content of the todo item via `todo.content`, when using a map function.

To illustrate this, you may refer to this code snippet:
https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-list-in-5min-2tomwb?file=/src/App.js